# How to view which web application is consuming resource

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd

I'm somehow a newbie on sysAdmin.

I have a Dedicated Server @Mediatemple and they're not supporting me on this issue.

So far I had an issue with MySQL Expensive Queries and I found a way how to determine which PHP Application is querying large amount of data which we don't need.

My issue now is ,that I can do a "**ps aux**" and I can see that a "**httpd**" service is consuming *CPU and Memory* more than others ,but I can't find out which **vhost** or application is doing that.

So is there a way how to find out from the HTTPD process, which application is causing that.

PS Our OS is CentOS 5.x with Apache2 and PHP5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check your access.log to see which URLs are requested the most.

If you need real-time information, you should configure [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html). It tells you what queries apache is currently working on.

Comment: With `ExtendedStatus On`, `mod_status` will tell you which PID is processing which URL and how long it has been processing for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) and set `newrelic_set_appname (string)` so that each of your applications will provide performance metrics.